# Angular ngRepeat fail to extract value from json object

Tags: angularjs

I have a json file "imgae A" which feeds the controller inside-which a `console.dir(data)`  outputs "image D".

The bindiing in the code below is failing to produce the item.name and just outputs blank line in its place "image B".

However, if I change {{item.name}} to just {{item}}, I get "image C"

Is my json wrong or the binding expression is wrong? Thanks

```html
<section>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <br/>
            <p>dummy</p>
            {{item.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Here is the controller as requested in the comments:

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller ('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
$http.get('js/mainMenu.json').then (function (data){
    $scope.menuItems = data;
    console.dir(data);
},
function(error){
    alert("http error");
});
}]);
```

[image]

Comment: post code your controller and get ng-controller page view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menuItems` is not the data returned in the http response. It is the http response itself, and you're iterating on its fields (data, status, statusText, etc.)

You probably have something like

```
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
    $scope.menuItems = response;
});
```

instead of

```
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
    $scope.menuItems = response.data;
});
```